# How to set timeZone for DatePicker from Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Is there any way to set the time zone on the datepicker from angular material 2?

**Component:**

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 7):

To set the timezone on the datepicker you need to create a custom DateAdapter as mentioned by @lee-richardson.

The following implementation is working on angular 11.0.0.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zbmhw5-n955ki

How I created this stackblitz:

0. I forked the stackblitz provided by the [Angular Material documentation illustrating the basic datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)
1. I Installed the moment-timezone dependency
2. I Created a custom-moment-date-adapter.ts and inherit from [MomentDateAdapter](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/11.0.0/src/material-moment-adapter/adapter/moment-date-adapter.ts) provided by Angular/Component. Then I have overrided `createDate`, `deserialize`, `parse` and `today` methods.

For the exemple I hardcoded the timezone but you can adapt the code to get the timezone from where you like.

```js
import { Inject, Injectable, Optional } from "@angular/core";
import { MomentDateAdapter } from "@angular/material-moment-adapter";
import { MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from "@angular/material/core";
import moment from "moment-timezone";

@Injectable()
export class CustomMomentDateAdapter extends MomentDateAdapter {
  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(MAT_DATE_LOCALE) dateLocale: string) {
    super(dateLocale);
  }

  static TIMEZONE = "Asia/Sakhalin";

  createDate(year: number, month: number, date: number): moment.Moment {
    // Moment.js will create an invalid date if any of the components are out of bounds, but we
    // explicitly check each case so we can throw more descriptive errors.
    if (month < 0 || month > 11) {
      throw Error(
        `Invalid month index "${month}". Month index has to be between 0 and 11.`
      );
    }

    if (date < 1) {
      throw Error(`Invalid date "${date}". Date has to be greater than 0.`);
    }

    const monthString = ("0" + (month + 1)).slice(-2);
    const yearSting = ("0" + date).slice(-2);
    const dateString = `${year}-${monthString}-${yearSting} 00:00`;
    const result = moment.tz(dateString, CustomMomentDateAdapter.TIMEZONE);

    // If the result isn't valid, the date must have been out of bounds for this month.
    if (!result.isValid()) {
      throw Error(`Invalid date "${date}" for month with index "${month}".`);
    }

    return result;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the given value if given a valid Moment or null. Deserializes valid ISO 8601 strings
   * (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) and valid Date objects into valid Moments and empty
   * string into null. Returns an invalid date for all other values.
   */
  deserialize(value: any): moment.Moment | null {
    let date;
    if (value instanceof Date) {
      date = this._createMoment2(value).locale(this.locale);
    } else if (this.isDateInstance(value)) {
      // Note: assumes that cloning also sets the correct locale.
      return this.clone(value);
    }
    if (typeof value === "string") {
      if (!value) {
        return null;
      }
      date = this._createMoment2(value, moment.ISO_8601).locale(this.locale);
    }
    if (date && this.isValid(date)) {
      return this._createMoment2(date).locale(this.locale);
    }
    return super.deserialize(value);
  }

  parse(value: any, parseFormat: string | string[]): moment.Moment | null {
    if (value && typeof value === "string") {
      return this._createMoment2(value, parseFormat, this.locale);
    }
    return value ? this._createMoment2(value).locale(this.locale) : null;
  }

  today(): moment.Moment {
    return moment()
      .utc()
      .tz(CustomMomentDateAdapter.TIMEZONE)
      .local(this.locale);
  }

  /** Creates a Moment instance while respecting the current UTC settings. */
  private _createMoment2(
    date: moment.MomentInput,
    format?: moment.MomentFormatSpecification,
    locale?: string
  ): moment.Moment {
    const date2 = moment(date, format, locale).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    return moment.tz(date2, CustomMomentDateAdapter.TIMEZONE);
  }
}
```

3. In the module (DemoMaterialModule in my stackblitz exemple):
   2.1) I Imported `MatMomentDateModule`
   2.2) I Injected the newly created `CustomMomentDateAdapter`

```js
providers: [{ provide: DateAdapter, useClass: CustomMomentDateAdapter }]
```

4. I updated `datepicker-overview-example` component for the purpose of this exemple.

Other references I used to find this solution:

- https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings
- [Angular Material custom datepicker format throws error "format.replace is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867168/angular-material-custom-datepicker-format-throws-error-format-replace-is-not-a)

Comment: this worked very well. Thank you.
To change the timezone dynamically you can change it within the component by `CustomMomentDateAdapter.TIMEZONE = 'UTC'`

Answer (score 3):

Technically I think the correct answer to your question is to create a custom DateAdapter

> This is accomplished by subclassing DateAdapter and providing your
>   subclass as the DateAdapter implementation.

However, if the underlying problem is that you're using the MomentDateAdapter and seeing odd time's in your date like `2019-05-01 23:00:00` when you actually clicked May 2, 2019 (which I see when I switch my timezone to London), then the solution is to set the moment date adapter to use UTC like:

```
{ provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: { useUtc: true } }
```

Then you should see May 2, 2019 go through as `2019-05-02 00:00:00`, as you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

For someone who uses luxon date adapter, I found this to be an easy solution. Provide luxon adapter:

```
import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import { LuxonDateAdapter, MAT_LUXON_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material-luxon-adapter';

providers: [
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: LuxonDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_LUXON_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS],
    },
  ],
```

Set time zone when needed (e.g., on app init, after fetching time zone from the server, etc.)

```
import { Settings } from 'luxon';

Settings.defaultZone = 'Europe/Berlin';
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the locale? You have to set it using the `MAT_DATE_LOCALE` token from Angular Material. From the docs:

> By default, the `MAT_DATE_LOCALE` injection token will use the existing `LOCALE_ID` locale code from `@angular/core`. If you want to override it, you can provide a new value for the `MAT_DATE_LOCALE` token:
>
> ```ts
> @NgModule({
>     providers: [
>         {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB'},
>     ],
> })
> export class MyApp {}
> ```
>
> It's also possible to set the locale at runtime using the `setLocale` method of the `DateAdapter`.
>
> ```ts
> import { DateAdapter, NativeDateAdapter } from '@angular/material';
>
> @Component({
>     selector: 'foo',
>     template: ''
> })
> export class FooComponent {
>     constructor(dateAdapter: DateAdapter<NativeDateAdapter>) {
>         dateAdapter.setLocale('de-DE');
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: does this set the locale only for this component or globally?